# Opera extension "A package with this name already exists"

Tags: opera-extension

I uploaded new add-on, but failed counting. So I've tried to upload again after delete it, but error message keeps coming up.

The error message is "A package with this name already exists. Please change the name or upgrade the existing package." Can you give me some advice please?

Comment: What do you mean by "failed counting"? Was the same error occurring before or it started to occur only after you've deleted the extension? What is the name of the extension?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry, my english isn't good enough. After our extension was reviewed, we had to fix the problem of it. And the I tried to upload revised one after delete old one, the error ocurred. The name of extension is Superpass. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In that case you need to somehow contact the moderators in order to restore your previous upload.

The extension name is already reserved.

We do so in order to prevent newly uploaded extension to fake some older and deleted one.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you tell me how I can contact the moderators please?

Comment: @KimSeongEun, every extension has it's own "wall". Writing on a wall is a way of contacting moderators. Since you've uploaded the extension again you should see it there: https://addons.opera.com/developer/ Now click on "Status: Not submitted". You can post messages there.